# Give Hex color code as a gridview background color

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

How can I give an hex color code to gridview's row background color? I know that it is to be given on a `rowdatabound` event. But I am not sure whether a hex color code can be given or a default - `System.Drawing.Color.(ColorName)` would only work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign a `System.Drawing.Color` type. But you can easily get the instance from hex or named values like shown below:

```
Color clr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF33");
```

named colors:

```
Color clr =  ColorTranslator.FromHtml("Red");
```

Also, you can directly specify the background/foreground color in the markup for gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" Runat="server" 
    ...
    <RowStyle ForeColor="red" BackColor="#FFF7E7"></RowStyle>
 </asp:GridView>
```

You can use both named and hex values.

Answer (score 0):

[Look here for conversions between int, string and hex values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)